# Having trouble while solving an array problem that produces an infinite loop

Tags: c++

Ask the user for a number between 1 and 9. If the user does not enter a number between 1 and 9, repeatedly ask for an integer value until they do. Once they have entered a number between 1 and 9, print the array.Given the array- `int array[] = { 4, 6, 7, 3, 8, 2, 1, 9, 5 }`;

```
#include<iostream>

int printArray(){
    int arraySize,i;
    int array[] = { 4, 6, 7, 3, 8, 2, 1, 9, 5 };

    arraySize=sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    std::cout<<"The length of the array is:"<<" "<<arraySize<<"\n";

    for(i=0;i<arraySize;i++){
        std::cout<<array[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
int main(){

    tryAgain:
    int x;
    std::cout<< "Enter any number between 1 and 9"<<"\n";
    std::cin>>x;

    if(x<=9 && x>=1){
        printArray();
    }
    else
        goto tryAgain;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `goto` for a simple "repeat until some condition` type loop. Have you tried printing `x` so you know what you are looking at? Also if `printArray()` doesn't need to return a value then make the function return type `void` not `int`

Comment: @John3136, I wouldn't be surprised if that's the issue. From the compiler's point of view, if reaching the end of the function means UB because of no return statement, the loop condition must never be true. Speaking of which, compilers warn about this.

Comment: @chris Is it UB if the result is never used? P.W.'s answer suggests it is, but I'm not so convinced that is the issue here since we never try to use the result...

Comment: You should indent your code correctly. BTW what is your question? Your program runs fine.

Comment: @John3136, It is in C++, but not C. (To be clear, it's only defined in C if not using the return value.)

Comment: Jabberwocky thanks for your suggestion. My program is resulting in an infinite loop when I am giving any character input instead of any number between 1 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is undefined behaviour caused by not returning a valid value from function `printArray` that is supposed to return an `int`.

The standard addresses this issue:

> **9.6.3 The return statement**
>   ...
>   2. ... Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function other than `main` results in undefined behavior.

Compiling with `-Wall` option in GCC produces this warning:

```
 warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

Since the function only prints data, you should have `void` instead of `int` as return type.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you shouldn't use `goto`, use `for`
2. The line `int printArray(){` should be `void printArray(){` for you needn't `return`

The follow `code` could work:

```
#include <iostream>

void printArray(){
    int arraySize, i;
    int array[] = { 4, 6, 7, 3, 8, 2, 1, 9, 5 };

    arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    std::cout << "The length of the array is:" << " " << arraySize << "\n";

    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
        std::cout<<array[i]<<"\n";
}

int main(){

    for (;;) {
        std::cout << "Enter any number between 1 and 9"<<"\n";
        int x;
        std::cin >> x;
        if(std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
            continue;
        }
        if (x < 1 || x > 9)
            continue;
        printArray();
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @John3136 your code is also producing the same problem that I was facing. It is resulting in infinite loop in dev c++ when I am giving any character input.

Comment: @SohiniGhosh fix it

Comment: your code is giving too many errors. and it is hard to understand.

Comment: @SohiniGhosh fix it use `std::cin`